# How can i cover my header with my splash screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I made a really simple splash screen for my website but i'm pretty new to react js and i don't know how to properly fix this problem.
The splash animation i made is composed by a js file and a css file. However when i load the website i see the loading screen but there is the header on top of that.
This is my app.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import "./App.css";
import Header from './components/header/Header';
import Home from './components/home/Home';
import About from './components/about/About';
import Skills from './components/skills/Skills';
import Services from './components/services/Services';
import Qualification from './components/qualification/Qualification';
import Work from './components/Portfolio/Work';
import Testimonials from './components/testimonials/Testimonials';
import Contact from './components/contact/Contact';
import Footer from './components/footer/Footer';
import ScrollUp from './components/scrollup/ScrollUp';

const App = () => {
return (
<>
  <Header />
  <main className='main'>
      <Home />
      <About />
      <Skills />
      <Services />
      <Qualification />
      <Work />
      <Testimonials />
      <Contact />
    </main><Footer /><ScrollUp />
  </>
)
}

export default App;
```

This is my splash screen code:

```
let intro = document.querySelector('.intro');
let logo = document.querySelector('.logo-header');
let logoSpan = document.querySelectorAll('.logo');

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=> {
setTimeout(()=>{

    logoSpan.forEach((span, idx)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            span.classList.add('active');
        },(idx +1)*400)
    });
    setTimeout(()=>{
        logoSpan.forEach((span, idx)=>{
            setTimeout(()=>{
                span.classList.remove('active');
                span.classList.add('fade');
            }, (idx +1)*50)
        })
    },2000);
    setTimeout(() => {
        intro.style.top = '-100vh';
    }, 2300);
  })
})
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/fabio.svg" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" 
/>
<!--=============== BOXICONS ===============-->
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.2/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<!--=============== UNICONS ===============-->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
<!--=============== SPLASH SCREEN LINK ===============-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="splash.css">
<title>Fabio Portfolio</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="intro">
  <h1 class="logo-header">
      <span class="logo">Fab</span><span class="logo">io</span>
  </h1>  
</div>

<div id="root"></div>
<script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
<script type="module" type src="splash.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```